# How to list wagtail pages in Django template?

Tags: python, django, wagtail

I have a site that is mostly made with Django but has a few content pages that need to be managed by Wagtail.

How can I link to the pages created with Wagtail in Django templates? I don't want to have to hardcode any of the pages. The client should be able to make a page in Wagtail and a link should be created to that page in Django templates.

The problem is that I don't know how to reference Wagtail pages through Django templates.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you say

> reference Wagtail pages through Django templates

I assume you mean render the navigation that will take the user to a page if they click on a navigation item.  To render the navigation for the page tree, in the a template file (typically `base.html`) you could do:

```
{% for item in request.site.root_page.get_children.live.in_menu %}
    <a href="{% pageurl item %}">{{ item.title }}</a>
{% endfor %}
```

The above is the simplest rendering of page navigation.  There are a number of other considerations you will likely run into when building navigation, one of which is building nested navigation.  I could also post about this if you need that information (I build unlimited nested navigation through a recursive call to a small fragment of html in a separate file from `base.html`).

Comment: You understand my intention completely.
When entering your code in my `base.html`, I don't get any results from the `for` loop.
My `base.html` is located in the templates folder of my Django root directory. I'm wondering if it is unable to detect Wagtail sites from there.

Comment: Have you included `wagtail.core.middleware.SiteMiddleware` in your `MIDDLEWARE` declaration in settings?

Comment: Yes. I do not manage all of my pages through Wagtail, though.

Comment: Please post your full `MIDDLEWARE` settings from your settings file.

Comment: `MIDDLEWARE = [
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
'wagtail.core.middleware.SiteMiddleware',
 'wagtail.contrib.redirects.middleware.RedirectMiddleware',
]`

Comment: The Wagtail `SiteMiddleware` should be placing `site` into `request`.  Try putting one or both of the following near the top of your template to see if it's there:  {{ request.site.root_page.get_children.live.in_menu }}    or {{ request.site }}.  (Reference:  https://github.com/wagtail/wagtail/blob/master/wagtail/core/middleware.py).  You could also set a debug breakpoint in `middleware.py` to determine what is happening there with the site lookup.

Comment: `{{ request.site.root_page.get_children.live.in_menu }}` renders "<PageQuerySet []>."
{{ request.site }} renders the proper name of my website.
For some reason, the for loop generates no hits. I have two content pages made using Wagtail. These pages properly insert content using `base.html` as a base.

Comment: I have figured it out. `{% for item in request.site.root_page.get_children %}` works. Thank you for your help.