# Consistent Wagtail menus showing parents, children and siblings

Tags: django, wagtail

I have a simple Wagtail site made of several pages of type **HomePage**  I want use Wagtails in-built menu system for all pages created from the **HomePage** model and **home_page.html** template. All the pages have **Show in menus:** selected.

Using this guide [here](https://www.accordbox.com/blog/wagtail-tutorial-12-how-create-and-manage-menus-wagtail-application/), I have created the following **get_context** method :

```
class HomePage(Page, Dreamer, Seo):

    def get_context(self, request):
        context = super(HomePage, self).get_context(request)
        context['menuitems'] = self.get_children().filter(live=True, show_in_menus=True)
```

... and placed the following code in my template :

```
{% for menu in menuitems   %}
    <a class="nav-item nav-link active" href="{{menu.url}}">{{menu.title}}</a>
{% endfor %}
```

Other than the root HomePage not showing at all, the menu displays the child pages, until I follow a link to a child page when all the links disappear (because the pages are no longer children).

Question: how do I get the menu show the root HomePage and also the child pages even when I am on a sibling, parent or child page?

Any help greatly received.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change:

`context['menuitems'] = self.get_children().filter(live=True, show_in_menus=True)`

to:

`context['menuitems'] = request.site.root_page.get_descendants(inclusive=True).live().in_menu()`

Comment: Thank you so much, how do you find things like this out?

Comment: I've been using/learning Wagtail for a year and a half, so I have a good code base for reference at this point.  Also, I've tried to familiarize myself with the docs.  In this case, the reference is at:  https://docs.wagtail.io/en/latest/reference/pages/model_reference.html#wagtail.core.models.Page.get_descendants.  One other thing on your question - if you don't need the root page (it's often just `/` in an `<a>` tag), then take a look at my answer here:  https://stackoverflow.com/a/59145493/5548239.  This code would save you from having to place the nav items in the context yourself.

Comment: There was some changes in wagtail 2.9: https://docs.wagtail.io/en/stable/releases/2.9.html#removed-support-for-django-2-1